# how to change follow button from follow to following with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, ajax

i created a following system in my website, and i have a follow button that is similar to twitter or facebook. when i click the follow button i want it to change to following and stays that way until the user clicks again. i tried doing this with jquery but so far i am struggling with making it work.

here is what i tried.

my jquery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){              

 $("#follow-button").click(function(){
  if ($("#follow-button").text() == "Follow"){
    $("#follow-button").text() == "Following";

}else{


 }
}); 
});
```

my html code:

```
     <button id="follow-button" class='msg-icon' name="follow" type="submit" >Follow    
            <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['search']; ?>" name="follow_id"/>
        </button>
```

how will i go about doing this, and what am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**when you get button text in include space first you remove space using trim() function and button change text using to text() in pass your text**

```
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#follow-button").click(function(){
                        if ($("#follow-button").text().trim() == "Follow"){
                            $("#follow-button").text('Following');
                        }else{
                            $("#follow-button").text('Follow');

                        }
                    });
                });
```

Comment: @chrisjamal this solution will replace even the hidden field which is inside button .

Comment: @Swati i know, thats why i added span tag instead so it doesnt conflict, but thank you for pointing out !!

Answer (score 0):

> Using [Paras Raiyani's Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62316834/8960497)

**UPDATED (2022)**

Toggle Follow and Following

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#follow-button").click(function() {
        value = ($(this).text() == "Follow") ? "Following" : "Follow";
         $(this).text(value);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="follow-button" class='msg-icon' name="follow" type="submit">Follow
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_GET['search']; ?>" name="follow_id" />
</button>
```